# Parse data and load html in a webview

Tags: android, webview

I have a URL, I used Jsoup to get data and remove header. But when I load to Webview some images not show, that is my problem.

My code here !

```
  @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).timeout(10 * 300)
                            .userAgent(USER_AGENT_MOBILE).get();
                    doc.outputSettings().escapeMode(EscapeMode.xhtml);
                    doc.select("div.header").remove();
                    String b = doc.toString();
                    webView.loadData(b, "text/html", "utf-8");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
}
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**use this**

```
byte[] imageRaw = null;
                    try {
                        URL url = new URL("http://some.domain.tld/somePicture.jpg");
                        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                        int c;
                        while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
                            out.write(c);
                        }
                        out.flush();

                        imageRaw = out.toByteArray();

                        urlConnection.disconnect();
                        in.close();
                        out.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    String image64 = Base64.encodeToString(imageRaw, Base64.DEFAULT);

                    String urlStr   = "http://example.com/my.jpg";
                    String mimeType = "text/html";
                    String encoding = null;
                    String pageData = "<img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64," + image64 + "\" />";

                    WebView wv;
                    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
                    wv.loadDataWithBaseURL(urlStr, pageData, mimeType, encoding, urlStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply... But I have settings webview in onCreate. Problem isn't settings webview :)

Comment: but you can make it global and use it anywhere in same class, or check image url separately over browser, opened or not ???

Answer (score 0):

Hello Iris Louis you have to use this method of WebView.

in below methos **result** is your html String which you are passing as a **b**.

> **`webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, result, "text/html", "utf-8", null);`**

This way your problem definitely solved.